# Which is the Best way to exit a method

Tags: java, methods, exit

I was looking for the ways to exit a method,
i found two methods
System.exit();
Return;

System.exit() - Exits the full program
Return exits current method and returns an error that remaining code are unreachable.

```
class myclass
{
    public static void myfunc()
    {
        return;
        System.out.println("Function ");
    }
}

public class method_test
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        myclass mc= new myclass();
        mc.myfunc();
        System.out.println("Main");
    }
}
```

Comment: Exit kills the entire program. return just leaves the current method.

Comment: your code kills a good programmer because the return statement has been used at the top of the rest of the code I mean if you have used this before your code an at the very beginning then your rest of code will become unreachable

Comment: Personally, I come from an out school of thought.  One entry, one exit.  Each non-void method should have one `return` statement and it should be the last statement in the method.  This makes the method easier to understand and read as you're not likely to miss a `return` statement hidden somewhere deep in some logic branch you weren't expecting, but that's just me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no best way, it depends on situation.

Ideally, there is no need to exit at all, it will just return.

```
int a() {
    return 2;
}
```

If there is a real need to exit, use return, there are no penalties for doing so.

```
void insertElementIntoStructure(Element e, Structure s) {
    if (s.contains(e)) {
        return; // redundant work;
    }
    insert(s, e); // insert the element
}
```

this is best avoided as much as possible as this is impossible to test for failure in voids

Avoid system.exit in functions, it is a major side effect that should be left to be used only in main.

```
void not_a_nice_function() {
    if (errorDetected()) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    print("hello, world!");
}
```

this pseudocode is evil because if you try to reuse this code, it will be hard to find what made it exit prematurely.

Comment: But Remaining codes after the return statement results an error method_test.java:6: error: unreachable statement System.out.println("Function ");

Comment: That only happens if the premature return is unconditional. If it's conditional, java will recognize that it can be reached.

Comment: Basically, you need to make an if statement, otherwise java is smart enough that the code will never be reached (due to unconditional jump).

Answer (score 3):

The best  and proper way to exit from method  is adding `return statement`.

**System.exit()** will shutdown your programm.

if you use `system.exit` once a thread goes there, it won't come back.

system.exit is part of [Design of the Shutdown Hooks API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html)

Comment: But Remaining codes after the return statement results an error 
method_test.java:6: error: unreachable statement
System.out.println("Function ");

Comment: @RajSekar  if you use system.exit  once a thread goes there, it won't come back.

Answer (score 2):

first of all your code will kill good programmers imagine this code [Which is the Best way to exit a method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16255267/2277645) this code example that how a return comes before a System.out.print(); as it becomes unreachable after the return statement lols
the command

```
         System.exit(int status); (status=0 for Normal Exit && status=-1 for abnormal exit
```

is only used if you want to exactly quit your whole app whereas
the command

```
         return;
```

is used to get out/return from a method
these two are different in their operations