# I'm working on a convex hull project using processing3, could somebody tell me if there's anyway to quit a function (not the whole program)?

Tags: java, algorithm, error-handling, processing

```
    int currentPoint = 2;
    int direction = 1;
    PVector copyOf(PVector p){
        return new PVector(p.x, p.y);
    }

    void addPoint() {

        hull.add(points.get(currentPoint));

    // look at the turn direction in the last three points
    // (we have to work with copies of the points because Java)
        p1 = copyOf(hull.get(hull.size() - 3));
        p2 = copyOf(hull.get(hull.size() - 2));
        p3 = copyOf(hull.get(hull.size() - 1));


        while (!crossprod (p1, p2, p3) && hull.size() > 2) {
    // if crossproduct is <= 0, then remove the middle point
    // if crossproduct is >= 0, do nothing because we have add the point before
            hull.remove(hull.size() - 2);
            if (hull.size() >= 3) {
    //in case of null pointer error
                p1 = copyOf(hull.get(hull.size() - 3));
            }
            p2 = copyOf(hull.get(hull.size() - 2));
            p3 = copyOf(hull.get(hull.size() - 1));
        }
    //you'll see information in the console
        println("currentPoint: " + currentPoint + " numPoints: " + points.size() + " hullSize: " + hull.size()+" direction:"+direction);
        if (currentPoint == points.size() -1 || currentPoint == 0) {
    //when direction = 1, it's a traversal of all points with O(n)
    //when direction = -1, the construction of convex hull began which is O(nlogn)
            direction = direction * -1;
            if (currentPoint == 0){
    /****add code here*****/
            }
        }

        currentPoint+= direction;
    }
```

It's quite hard to explain my question clearly without code. I want to add some code so that when `currentPoint = 0`, it will quit the `addpoint()` function. `exit()` won't work, for it will quit the whole program and the animation already played will disappear. I can't think up any good solution to that, do anybody has ideas about that?

Comment: add a `return;`..that shall work(without looking at the rest of your implementation).

Comment: more info http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: In the future, please try to post a [mcve] instead of your whole program. A simple program is much easier to debug. Also please try to use proper formatting, as right now your code is very hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/return.html):

> The keyword `return` may also be used to break out of a function, thus not allowing the program to the remaining statements.
>
> ```
> void draw() {
>   background(204);
>   line(0, 0, width, height);
>   if (mousePressed) {
>     return;  // Break out of draw(), skipping the line statement below
>   }
>   line(0, height, width, 0);  // Executed only if mouse is not pressed
> }
> ```

So in your case:

> I want to add some code so that when currentPoint = 0, it will quit the addpoint() function.

```
if(currentPoint == 0){
  return;
}
```

Taking a step back, you should really get into the habit of doing some research. A quick google search of "java quit function" returns a bunch of results, including:

- [How to break out or exit a method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7937029/how-to-break-out-or-exit-a-method-in-java)
- [Which is the Best way to exit a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255267/which-is-the-best-way-to-exit-a-method)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return;
```

or

```
return <optional object>;
```